# Help for out of memory

Tags: rendering

So
I am making a animation and as a part of it i require hundereds of people fight for a war scene with some main charecters
But the problem is my system is not powerful enough to render even a image so it gives out of memory error
I am on blender 2.79 Cycles render
Does anyone know a alternative

Comment: You might look into using a render farm, however most, if not all of them carry a fee.

Comment: Thank you      i also have a intel hd graphics card but it doesnt show up in blender

Comment: Do you know how to use it

Comment: I see a few options: adjust your ambitions to match the computing capabilities within your reach , or invest a lot of money on extremely powerful computers with many powerful GPUs, or use a entender farm. But probably the first option is the most realistic.